# How to create a Task Scheduler executing a search function and exporting it to a PDF document?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I need to create a Task Scheduler that will be able to run a console app that searches the Active Directory and then export that information to a PDF file.  At the moment in my app I can do it manually and it will display in a `ListView` then I have the ability to export that info to a PDF document.

So I have created an console app but it only displays the last line in the search in my PDF?

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
 namespace EnabledUsers
{
class Program
{
    public static string DomainName { get; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetUsersInGroup();
    }
    public static void GetUsersInGroup()
    {
        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DomainName);
        UserPrincipal userPrin = new UserPrincipal(ctx) { Enabled = true };
        userPrin.Name = "*";
        var searcher = new System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalSearcher();
        searcher.QueryFilter = userPrin;
        var results = searcher.FindAll();


        if (results != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal p in results)
            {

                Console.Write(p.SamAccountName);
                Console.WriteLine(p.Name);

                var creationDate = string.Empty;
                var lastLogon = string.Empty;
                var pwdlastset = string.Empty;
                var company = string.Empty;
                var prop = string.Empty;
                var directoryEntry = p.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                prop = "whenCreated";
                if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
                {
                    creationDate = directoryEntry.Properties[prop].Value.ToString();
                }
                prop = "lastlogon";
                if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
                {
                    lastLogon = directoryEntry.GetLastLogon().ToString();
                }
                prop = "pwdLastSet";
                if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
                {
                    pwdlastset = directoryEntry.GetLastPwdChange().ToString();
                }
                prop = "company";
                if (directoryEntry.Properties.Contains(prop))
                {
                    company = directoryEntry.Properties[prop].Value.ToString();
                }

                Console.Write(creationDate);
                Console.Write(lastLogon);
                Console.Write(pwdlastset);
                Console.Write(company);

                try
                {
                    Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream("Salman.pdf", FileMode.Create));

                    myDocument.Open();

                    iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 6);
                    iTextSharp.text.Font font6 = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD, 8);
                    PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(1);

                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(6);
                    float[] columnWidths = new float[] { 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f, 15f };
                    table.SetWidths(columnWidths);
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name", font6)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("LanID", font6)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("When Created", font6)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Last Logon", font6)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Last Password Reset", font6)));
                    table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company", font6)));

                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(p.Name, font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(p.SamAccountName, font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(creationDate, font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(lastLogon, font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(pwdlastset, font5));
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(company, font5));




                    myDocument.Add(table);
                    myDocument.Close();

                }
            catch (DocumentException de)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(de.Message);
            }
            catch (IOException ioe)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ioe.Message);
            }

        }
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the code in a console app?  If that works then you can create a scheduled task with Windows.

Comment: I am thinking of doing that but am a bit confused (to be honest) on how to being able to run it in order of search then export to pdf?

Comment: At the moment you click on a button then it searches AD, then once that is done then you click on another button to export to PDF

Comment: Okay, so the search and export are bits of code.  Put them in a console app and run it and make sure it does the same thing.

Comment: Cool, Ill give that a go....

Comment: Okay seems to be working, however it only shows the last line of the search in the PDF document?  I have updated my question with the code I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because these lines

```
Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream("Salman.pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

should not be inside your loop. You are basically creating a new PDF every time you process a new result, and overwriting the previous version at the same time.

You need to create the PDF once, before your loop starts, and then keeping adding more things to the same document. Move those lines to just before `foreach (Principal p in results)` and it should work.